# Can depth be used as a feature when predicting rock type from well log data?

Tags: training, svm

I am trying to predict the lithofacies, *i.e.* the rock type, from well log data, a project very similar to the one described in [this tutorial](https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Facies_classification_using_machine_learning).

A well log can be seen as a 1D curve tracking how a given property (*e.g.* gamma radiation, electrical resistivity, etc...) varies as a function of depth. The idea is to use these 1D arrays as the input features to train a Machine Learning model (*e.g.* SVM or Random Forest), to infer the facies at a given depth. For instance, in the image below:

- the first 5 tracks (GR to PE) are the well logs used as features
- while the last 2 tracks (Facies and Prediction) correspond to the true and predicted facies.

[image]

One of my colleague started using *depth* as a feature, thus obtaining much higher scores than when working with well logs only.

While this may make sense from a geological standpoint, as certain rock types are expected within a given depth range, <s>I think that this will cause model overfitting</s> **[EDIT from June 1, 2022]** I am concerned that doing so would put "too much constraint" on the model.

**Is this explanation correct, or may depth (or position) be used as a feature to train a ML model?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problem using `depth`. Instead of putting "too much constraint" on, I would say it provide "extra information" or "predictive power" to the model, just like the well logs. This is what a feature does.

Think it in another way, if `depth` would harm the model (say by 'overfit'), I can argue that any of the 5 tracks of well log features could do the same.

As a separate topic, "putting extra constraint on a model" usually *ease* overfitting, which is often done deliberately. This technique is called [regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Ipounng! You make a valid point: I know regularization from geophysical data inversion and it does indeed prevent overfitting by promoting a certain behavior (*e.g.* smoothness or "blockyness"). In that regards, you are right that constraining the model prevents it from overfitting.

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase my question properly. Imagine an algorithm aiming to identify a given target (*e.g.* a dog) from a series of photos. Would it make sense to use the position of the dog in each picture as a feature?

Comment: No sure if the dog example is a good comparison to the original question, but yes! ( if we know whereabouts a dog is in advance) This points the model to focus on important area thus improving performance.

Comment: Another example from medical field: given some medical images (X-ray/MRI etc.), task to identify whether a certain tumor exist or not. A popular strategy is to train a model to seek potential areas which such tumor potentially exists (segmentation phase), then use these areas as input to train another model which classify if a tumor exists or not.

Comment: This is a great example!

Comment: Now the challenge becomes creating a training dataset that is varied enough to ensure good generalization. To go back to the dog example, I would not want to train my model using only pictures where the dog appears in the lower left corner!

Comment: True! Otherwise the model may be biased to keep looking at that corner. And this is a reason why we do image augmentation / a lot of random cropping and centering etc. in image classification to prevent overfitting.